Slice category of simplicial presheaves
If $\mathcal{C}$ is a small category and we let $\mathbf{Pre}(\mathcal{C})$ denote the category of presheaves over $\mathcal{C}$, then it is well known that for any presheaf $X \in \mathbf{Pre}(\mathcal{C})$, there is an equivalence of categories
$$ \mathbf{Pre}(\mathcal{C})_{/X} \simeq \mathbf{Pre}(\smallint X)$$
where $\smallint X$ is the category of elements of $X$.
I would like to know if there is a similar result for simplicial presheaves. I.e. given a simplicial presheaf $X$ on $\mathcal{C}$, is there a 1-category $\smallint_{\mathsf{\Delta}} X$ (or maybe even a simplicial category) along with a Quillen equivalence
$$\mathbf{sPre}(\mathcal{C})_{/X} \simeq \mathbf{sPre}(\smallint_{\mathsf{\Delta}} X),$$
where we consider the left hand side with the slice model structure inherited from the projective model structure on $\mathbf{sPre}(\mathcal{C})$ and the right hand side is equipped with the projective model structure.
Now abstractly this must exist by Dugger's Theorem. However, the construction given in that theorem seems not amenable to computations.
Now after reading Jardine's paper, see Examples 2 and 3, I have a candidate for $\smallint_{\mathsf{\Delta}} X = EX$, let it denote the category whose objects are maps of simplicial presheaves $\Delta^n \times y(U) \to X$, where $\Delta^n$ is considered as a constant simplicial presheaf and $y(U)$ is the representable presheaf on $U \in \mathcal{C}$, considered as a discrete simplicial presheaf, and where morphisms are those maps $\Delta^n \times y(U) \to \Delta^m \times y(V)$ over $X$ induced by simplicial maps $\sigma : [n] \to [m]$ and maps $f : U \to V$ in $\mathcal{C}$. In other words, this is the category of elements of $X$ thought of as a presheaf $(\Delta \times C)^\text{op} \to \mathbf{Set}$.
There are lots of partial results in the above Jardine paper about simplicial presheaves on $EX$. However, it doesn't seem like the desired Quillen equivalence follows from anything in that paper. If $X$ is the nerve of a presheaf of groupoids, then there is a similar result, Theorem 5.2 of Hollander.
I am curious if there is a reference in the literature showing the above Quillen equivalence (or a disproof!) for the candidate category above.

Let me also say why I'm interested in this. I want to get a handle on using truncation and connectedness arguments using homotopy group sheaves from Rezk's notes on model toposes.
There he defines homotopy sheaves by first taking a model topos $E$, an object $X \in E$, and considering the slice model topos $E/X$. Then letting $i : * \to S^n$ denote a fixed basepoint, we have $X^i : X^{S^n} \to X$, and taking truncation $\tau_{\leq 0} X^i : \tau_{\leq 0} X^{S^n} \to \tau_{\leq 0} X$ gives us an object in $\tau_{\leq 0} E/X$. Now what I want is to get a hands-on description of $\tau_{\leq 0} E/X$, given a hands-on description of $E$, i.e. suppose I define $E$ as simplicial presheaves on a site $(\mathcal{C}, j)$, equipped with the Cech projective model structure. Rezk proves abstractly that $E/X$ will then be a model topos. He then uses Dugger's theorem to obtain a small presentation of $E/X$ and uses that to define all the truncations $\tau_{\leq k} E/X$. So, if I can obtain a workable small presentation of $E/X$, then I can do the computations I want.

My idea for this so far: by the first equivalence for presheaves, we have
$$\mathbf{sPre}(\mathcal{C})/_X \simeq \mathbf{Pre}(\Delta \times \mathcal{C})_{/X} \simeq \mathbf{Pre}(EX).$$ Now we want to compare $\mathbf{sPre}(EX)$ and $\mathbf{Pre}(EX)$. Maybe we transfer the projective model structure across the equivalence to $\mathbf{Pre}(EX)$, and then try to prove that we have a Quillen equivalence using $\pi_0 : \mathbf{sPre}(EX) \rightleftarrows \mathbf{Pre}(EX) : {}^c(-)$, where ${}^c(-)$ takes a presheaf and thinks of it as a discrete simplicial presheaf. Another approach could be to rewrite $\mathbf{sPre}(EX)$ as
$$[\Delta^\text{op}, \mathbf{Pre}(EX)] \simeq [\Delta^\text{op}, \mathbf{sPre}(\mathcal{C})_{/X}] = \mathbf{ssPre}(\mathcal{C})_{/{}^cX}$$
where here ${}^c X$ is thought of as a discrete bisimplicial presheaf. Then have an adjunction using the diagonal functor, and we try to show Quillen equivalence by transferring again.
But I'm kind of stuck here. Any help would be appreciated.

Alright, I've nearly gotten this thanks to Point 14 of Dmitri Pavlov in this link. Maybe somebody could help me with the very last bit. This will be a little sketchy, if I figure out the whole thing I'll post a more detailed answer.
We have a an adjunction of $1$-categories
$$\mathbf{sPre}(\smallint X) \underset{R}{\overset{L}{\rightleftarrows}} \mathbf{sPre}(\mathcal{C})_{/X}$$
where $L$ is defined by sending a representable $y(\Delta^n \times y(U) \xrightarrow{\sigma} X)$ to the corresponding map $\sigma \in \mathbf{sPre}(\mathcal{C})_{/X}$ and then extending by colimits. The right adjoint $R$ is then defined for $f : Y \to X$ by $R(f)(\sigma)$, which is the pullback of $* \xrightarrow{\sigma} X(U)^{\Delta^n} \xleftarrow{f_U^{\Delta^n}} Y(U)^{\Delta^n}$. This is precisely the enriched Hom $\underline{\mathbf{sPre}(\mathcal{C})_{/X}}(\sigma, f)$. Now if we equip $\mathbf{sPre}(\int X)$ with the projective model structure, then by examining $R$ and doing some lifting calculus, we see that it preserves fibrations and trivial fibrations. Thus we have a Quillen pair. Let $D$ denote the set of maps of representables
$$D = \{ y(\Delta^n \times y(U) \xrightarrow{\sigma} X) \xrightarrow{\phi \times 1_{y(U)}} y(\Delta^m \times y(U) \xrightarrow{\tau} X) \}$$
We want to show that the Quillen pair above descends to the left bousfield localization $L_D \mathbf{sPre}(\int X)$. By Prop 3.3 here, this holds because $L$ is already derived on $D$ and the maps clearly are weak equivalences since all $\Delta^k$ are weak equiv to each other.
Now all that is left is to show that this is a Quillen equivalence. We can show that $R$ reflects weak equivalences between fibrant objects, and then my plan was to use Prop 2.3 here to show the Quillen equivalence. But I'm getting stuck again here, how do I show that the regular unit is a weak equivalence in $L_D \mathbf{sPre}(\int X)$? I'll come back to this later, maybe somebody else will figure it out in the meantime.

Note that If "simplicial category" means categories objects in simplicial set ( so with both a simplicial set of objects and a simplicial set of morphism), then there is a simplicial category $\int_\Delta X$ such that you have a littleral equivalence of categories instead of just a Quillen equivalence.

To go from there to a simplicially enriched category, you should start by looking at the case of just sSet/X for X a simplicial sets. This is definitely possible, but the construction is not going to be very simple (nor very explicit). In the general case you want to do something similar applied to the simplicial set of object of your simplicial category but also  take into account the morphism part... Given your motivation I feel like working with the simplicial category might be the best way to proceed.

Let me see if I follow: Think of $EX$ as a category internal to $\mathbf{sSet}$. Thats easy enough. There should be some notion of the category of presheaves on $EX$ internal to $\mathbf{sSet}$. Quickly looking on the nlab, this seems a bit more involved (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/internal+profunctor)? I assume then that the claim is that $\mathbf{sPre}(\mathcal{C})_{/X} \simeq \mathcal{D}$, where $\mathcal{D}$ is the category of presheaves on $EX$ internal to $\mathbf{sSet}$? I'm not quite seeing how this helps me find a small presentation in the sense of Dugger though.

Maybe that's what your second comment is alluding to though.

Yes, that's what I'm alluding too in my second message: going all the way to a simplicially enriched category is possible, but not super easy or very explicit (as I say, look at the sort of thing you would have to do for the simplest case of sSet/X). Maybe it would be better to not try to do that and work with the simplicial category instead - but that's just an opinion.

Ahhh Dmitri Pavlov has already solved this! Point 14 of https://nforum.ncatlab.org/discussion/13571/#Item_21 explains it. What I was missing was that we also have to localize at all the representable simplicial maps. When/if I actually fully understand this, I'll add the answer.

Yes, if you allow yourselve to take a Bousfield localization of the presheaves categories at some arrow this is much easier. I didn't mentioned that because it felt to me more different from what you asked (you are no longer working with a presheaves categories, but a localization of one), but if that suit your goal, great!

Yes this suits my goal, I had totally forgotten that small presentations allow you to take left Bousfield localizations. If there are any references proving Pavlov’s assertion please let me know.
